# Django StreamingHttpResponse not streaming on production API

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, django-rest-framework, openai-api

I'm trying to stream an OpenAI response from a Django server to the browser.

I have a view in Django that looks like this (assume that `generate_thing` returns a stream from OpenAI):

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def generate(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    result = generate_thing(data)
    return StreamingHttpResponse(result)
```

Whenever I run this locally, it works exactly as expected.
When I upload my Django code to EC2 and try to call it directly on its IP address, it works exactly as expected.
However, when I run it through a proxy like API Gateway or Nginx, it waits until the stream has completely finished to return a response.

I tried setting `Content-Type` to `text/event-stream` before returning it like

```
response = StreamingHttpResponse(result)
response['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
return response
```

and it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off setting this up as a socket connection. You generally don't want to do blocking connections on regular http responses.

Comment: Is there an easy way to do that in Django?

Comment: Give this a try. https://realpython.com/getting-started-with-django-channels/

Comment: Got around to implementing this. How can I handle multiple concurrent requests?

Comment: Are you not running behind gunicorn and nginx? Gunicorn handles your threading for multiple requests at once. There is also uvicorn and other servers but the gist is you run Django behind one of those services and have nginx proxy pass to it. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/